# Why doesn't this C code change the string and cause a buffer overflow?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char String[] = "Hello the world!";
    char *pointer = String;
    int i;

    printf(" %s\n", pointer);

    pointer = "Helllooooo the worlldddddd";
    printf("Hello %s\n", pointer);
    printf("Hello %s\n", String);

    return 0;
}
```

but I can't understand how this line works fine.

```
pointer = "Helllooooo the worlldddddd";
```

but I got this output

```
 Hello the world!
Hello Helllooooo the worlldddddd
Hello Hello the world!
```

As you see it couldn't change `String` value but it shows more than the original number of characters. Shouldn't this cause a buffer overflow? Won't that destroy other variables?

Comment: `"Hello the world!"` and `"Helllooooo the worlldddddd"` are two different strings, located in two different parts of memory. With `pointer = ...`, you are setting `pointer` to be the address of either one of these strings (i.e., setting it to point to that string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write the line

```
pointer="Helllooooo the worlldddddd";
```

you are not saying "take the array pointed at by `pointer` and overwrite its contents with the string `"Helllooooo the worlldddddd"`," but rather "change *which string* `pointer` points at so that it's now pointing at the string `""Helllooooo the worlldddddd"`." This accounts for why you're seeing the original string printed out when you directly print `String` - you never actually modified it. As a result, you don't need to worry about overflowing your array here, since you're not actually writing anything to it.

On the other hand, if you wrote

```
strcpy(pointer, "Helllooooo the worlldddddd");
```

which actually *does* copy the contents of the new string into the buffer pointed at by `pointer`, then you *would* have a buffer overflow, which would be a problem. But notice that this is a very different operation that explicitly says "please copy the contents of this string to this location" rather than "change where this pointer points."

Comment: @JohnH - I do not believe `String` is considered `const`, implicit or otherwise, so although more space cannot be added to `String`, for example with `realloc(...)`,  it can be modified.  If it was implicit `const`, I would think it would throw a compile time error as opposed to a run-time error.  Is there a specific environment where you have observed otherwise?

Comment: @JohnH, no `String` must be mutable. It is not pointing to the string literal but a completely separate array of `char` that is not `const` qualified. So per se there is no problem modifying it. (There is obviously a problem with the size, though.)

Answer (score 1):

you have initialize a pointer which point to String "Hello the world " `char *pointer=String;` so far so good .
first printf `printf(" %s\n",pointer);`, you have printed the pointer which point to "Hello the world".
then you set the pointer to point anew string "Hellloooooo the worllddddd" `pointer="Helllooooo the worlldddddd";`.
then you have printed the pointer which point in this case to "Hellloooooo the worllddddd"`printf("Hello %s\n",pointer);` .
last printf you have printed the string "Hello the world" `printf("Hello %s\n",String);`.
Note:.
((takecare that you have printed in second `printf("Hello %s\n",String);` and third printf `printf("Hello %s\n",String);` the string hello which will be printed before the value of the pointer or the string))

Answer (score 1):

One more quick option for you to consider when manipulating strings:
The string function *[strdup(...);](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdupa.3.html)* allows the copying of an existing string into a newly created string in one easy step.  *(or at least one in which all the complexity has been abstracted away)*:

```
 char *pointer = strdup("Helllooooo the worlldddddd");
```

The new string  `pointer` can now be used to contain any string up to `len` long, where `len` is defined as:

```
int len = strlen(pointer);//len is 26 after using strdup(...); above
```

So for example, because your example string is shorter than `len`:

```
char String[]="Hello the world!";//length is 16
```

you could copy it into `pointer` without a buffer overflow:

```
strcpy(pointer, String);
```

Strings created using `strdup(...):` need to be free'd to avoid memory leaks.  Call the following when you are finished using `pointer`:

```
free(pointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char String[]="Hello the world";  // the string
char *pointer=String;             // pointer to string 
char i;                           //counter

printf(" %s\n",pointer);          // print current value of pointer

pointer="number of char";         // new value to replace the string
for (i=0;i<14;i++)                // you cannot change the content of array without using loop
{
String[i] = pointer[i];           // char i in string = ti char i in pointer
}
printf("Hello   %s\n",pointer);   // print value of pointer
printf("Hello   %s\n",String);    // print value of string

return 0;
}
```

i think that what are you trying to do.